# How to pass numeric values from PhP to Javascript without posting data?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, transit

I need some data from SQL to Javascript, so I called them in PhP and I'm trying to pass these values to Javascript, but the code below causes a NaN failure... if I set a PhP command for the Javascript variable, I can't use it as a numeric value...

```
<?php
  $val=12;
?>
<script>
  var val="<?php echo $val; ?>";
</script>
```

I got a solution but I'm sure, this is not the best way to do this:

```
<?php
  $val=12;
?>
<input type="number" id="val" name="val" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" hidden>
<script>
  var val=getElementById('val').value;
</script>
```

Comment: Change ``getElementById`` to ``document.getElementById()`` also as @MagnusEriksson said need some more information regarding **$val** and other **errors**

Comment: Maybe you should get rid of the quotes: `var val=<?php echo $val; ?>;`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "document." tag, but of course in my script didn't.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is removing the quotes:

```
<script>
  var val = <?php echo $val; ?>;
</script>
```

But there may be edge cases in which php yields unexpected results, so in my opinion it's a good practice to keep the quotes and to update the value.

If you are sure that the value will always be an integer and/or that you need an integer in your code you can do:

```js
var numericValue = parseInt(val, 10);
```

Or if you are using lodash:

```js
var numericValue = _.parseInt(val);
```

Remember to pass 10 as the second parameter which will specify the radix in the first case, as there may be edge cases in which numbers are interpreted with a base different than 10 (like hexadecimal or binary).

Otherwise if the value can be a float I suggest to do:

```js
var numericValue = parseFloat(val);
```

And if you want to limit the digits after the decimal point you can do:

```js
var numericValue = Number(parseFloat(val).toFixed(4));
```

`.toFixed()` returns a string so if you still need a number it's better to convert it back to a number with the `Number()` function.

Passing the value through an input may work but it doesn't look like a good practice, anyway to get the element you will need to add `document` before `getElementById`:

```js
var val = document.getElementById('val').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! It's easier, then I thought! I thought, quotes are always needed, as JavaScript identify "<?php" tag as string.